# Magneto2.3.1 How to Return of Product?

Tags: magento2.3.1, rma

I am using Magneto2.3.1 I need to When customers want to return a product, they have to fill in a return form. The customer must fill in this form directly online. After finishing it he should be able to confirm it, by klicking on a button `«ok»`. This generates an email which is sent to: `info@xxx.ch`. After that, the customer has to be able to print this form (generated pdf) The form should look something like the enclosed file `«Retourenformular»`

If any one idea how to do this and if any suggested plugin reply me

Comment: Search for "RMA for Magento 2" as it is provided many extension providers such as Mirasvit, Amasty, etc.

Comment: @AmritPalSingh Yes but actually my requirement wise what extetnions ful fill please check it this is full fill https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-rma/#easy-rma-requests-for-guests

Comment: because  After that, the customer has to be able to print this form (generated pdf)